# Can someone explain to me how the xs values "xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]" are being transfered to "height"? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to understand how the xs values "xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]" are being transferred to "height". How come we have "maxheight" instead of just "height" as our variable? I don't understand the logic of this specific part of the code. Thank you.

```
import turtle

def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.begin_fill()               # start filling this shape
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()                 # stop filling this shape



xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]  # here is the data
maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 10

wn = turtle.Screen()             # Set up the window and its attributes
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border, 0-border, 40*numbars+border, maxheight+border)
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

tess = turtle.Turtle()           # create tess and set some attributes
tess.color("blue")
tess.pensize(3)



for a in xs:
    if a < 100:
        tess.fillcolor("green")
    elif 100 <= a < 200:
        tess.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        tess.fillcolor("red")
    drawBar(tess, a)

wn.exitonclick()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btGcv.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But maybe you are missing out the function call `drawBar(tess, a)` in a for loop over all values of `xs`?

Comment: You loop over `xs` with `for a in xs:`. In the loop you call `drawBar(tess, a)` where `a` is the second parameter. In the function `drawBar` your second parameter has the name `height`, so that is where `height` comes from.

Comment: This same source code has shown up on SO multiple times, could you include a link to it's origin?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you play with the code. If you do not understand why "maxheight" Is used as a variable instead of "height" change the "maxheight" variable to "height" and see what happens.  Do not worry you will not break your computer. Simply run the new code.

After that look at the code and remember a variable can be named anything within the rules of python. Maxheight could have been named dog cat or or rabbit. The word height also could have been anything perhaps a letter a, B or C. Look at where the programmer put the word "height". "Ask your self was height the name of an argument with in the function drawbar?  Then look at the line of code maxheight = max(xs).

Is that a variable? Is the programmer assigning the name maxheight to pythons built in function max. In this case the function max is taking one argument the list xs. From this point on in the code every time you call maxheight you are runnig the built in function max on the list xs.

I humbly suggest you do two things to thoroughly understand this part of the code. Google and review variables then functions and arguments in python.